# Create a single row result from a multiple row table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks like this:

```
id       value
1         0
1         0
1         5
1         0
2         0
2         0
2         10
2         0
```

I would like my result set to look like:

```
id   value     value     value    value      etc.
1    0         0         5        0
2    0         0         10       0
```

Comment: which RDBMS are you using? MySQL, SQL server, Oracle, ...?

Comment: Look in to pivot / dynamic pivot

Comment: SQL does not return the records in a defined order if you don't define one BTW.

Comment: Thank you.  I am using SQL Server.

Comment: Its a bit tricky because of the repeating values ...

Answer (score 0):

Best I can do for you is this (assuming MySQL)

```
SELECT   id, GROUP_CONCAT(value ORDER BY value ASC SEPARATOR ',')
FROM     tbl
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: I think there is a STUFF() function that is similar